# How to get config database server programatically?

Tags: 2013, development, database

I would like to use C# to get the server name and instance (e.g. `myserver/instance1`) where configuration database of the local farm resides. I don't want to use PowerShell. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm` and look for [Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.servers(v=office.15).aspx) in the farm.

```
public String GetSharePointSQLServerName()
{
    String sServerName = "notFound";
    foreach (var item in SPFarm.Local.Servers)
    {
        foreach (var svc in item.ServiceInstances)
        {
            if (svc is SPDatabaseServiceInstance)
            {
                SPDatabaseServiceInstance s = svc as SPDatabaseServiceInstance;
                sServerName = item.DisplayName + "\\" + s.Instance;
            }
        }
    }
    return sServerName;
}
```

**To find config database**

```
var dbInstance = (SPDatabaseServiceInstance) svc;
{
    if (db.GetType().ToString().CompareTo("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase") == 0)
    {
        configDb = db;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I can iterate all servers like this, but how do I actually know which one stores the configuration database? AFAIK the above code can return multiple results (i.e. multiple `SPDatabaseServiceInstances`).

Comment: @w128 updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to do it. I ended up doing it like this: `foreach (var db in dbInstance.Databases) { if (db.TypeName.Equals("Configuration Database")) return db; }`

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint stores `ConfigDb` connection string in Windows Registry you could utilize the following approach for retrieving Config Db server name:

```
public static string GetConfigDbConnectionString()
{
    var farm = SPFarm.Local;
    var version = farm.BuildVersion.Major.ToString() + "." + farm.BuildVersion.Minor.ToString();
    var configDbKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\{0}\Secure\ConfigDB",version));
    if (configDbKey != null)
    {
        var connString = configDbKey.GetValue("dsn").ToString();
        return connString;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var configDbConnString = GetConfigDbConnectionString();
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(configDbConnString);
Console.WriteLine(builder.DataSource);  //print server name
```